# How to select data from two different tables and count rows

Tags: sql-server

i have two tables: TableA, TableB

```
TableA
-------
Aid | name | status
--------------------
45  | xyz  | pending
26  | abc  | completed

TableB 
------
id | Aid | completed | exception
--------------------------------
1 |  45 |    1       |   NULL
2 |  45 |    1       |   Null
3 |  26 |    1       |   Null
4 |  26 |   NULL     |    1
```

i want to select from both tables like this:

```
Aid | name | status  | completed | exception | Total
-----------------------------------------------------
 45 | xyz  | pending |    2      |    0      |   2
 26 | abc  |completed|    1      |    1      |   2
```

How to combine below two queries into one query :

`select id,name, status from TableA;`

`select Count(*) as Total, COUNT(v.completed), COUNT(v.exception) from TableB as v where v.Aid= TableA.Aid;`

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT A.id AS Aid, A.Name, A.status, SUM(B.completed) AS completed, SUM(b.exception) AS exception, COUNT(B.completed + B.exception) AS TOTAL
FORM TableA AS A
LEFT JOIN TableB AS B
  ON A.id = B.Aid
GROUP BY A.id, A.Name, A.status, B.Aid
```